# gulp-clean-css cleaning / removing duplicated css when using @extend

Tags: sass, gulp, extend, gulp-clean-css

I'm having a weird problem with @extend on scss. when i extend some %placeholder that have repetitive properties, the gulp-clean-css merge them, and I don't want that to happen.

Here's an example:
*foo.scss*

```
%one {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 95%;
}

%two {
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}


.foo {
    @extend %one;
    @extend %two;
}


.foo2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

*foo.min.css*

```
.foo{font-size:1rem;width:calc(100% - 10px);}
.foo2{font-size:16px;font-size:1rem}
```

Why does this happen?

If it helps, this is mine gulp-task:

```
gulp.task('scss', function(){
    console.log('start task scss');
    gulp.src(folderStyles)
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie9', noAdvanced: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folderStyles));
    logEnv();
});
```

Is there any other better plugin to use?
I don't want it to remove duplicated properties. If you ask me why, it's because of old browsers support than might not support `rem` or `calc`, or other "new fancy propertie" ;)

Thank you :)

Comment: There's a good chance you can play with some of the clean-css settings (gulp-clean-css is just a wrapper for the node library) to accomplish what you want. Perhaps `--skip-aggressive-merging`?  https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css

Comment: how do i add that on my gulp task?

Comment: see my answer below. I believe that has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this, and I think your setting is incorrect for 'noAdvanced':

**Instead of:**

```
.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie9', noAdvanced: true}))
```

**Use:**

```
.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie9', advanced: false}))
```

**According to the docs:**

> *advanced* - set to false to disable advanced optimizations - selector &
>   property merging, reduction, etc.

https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-api

This isn't going to leave you with 1 .foo selector with two font-size declarations tho, it's just not going to merge the two, so you'll end up having:

```
.foo {
    font-size:16px;
    width:95%
}
.foo {
    font-size:1rem;
    width:calc(100% - 10px)
}
.foo2{
    font-size:16px;
    font-size:1rem
}
```

This answers your issue however kind of defeats the purpose of using something like clean-css.  I'm curious as to why you would want to leave both font-size declarations in your CSS when the first one will be overridden anyway.

Comment: Answering your question, it's because of old browsers than might not support `rem` or `calc`. ;) Ideally this should have like: "ignoreProperties: 'rem', 'calc', 'display'". That way it would merge all except these properties.